# Convertion of date format using jQuery or javascript(Without using any lib)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

How can i convert this `2016-01-05 04:06:52`  format of date to a standard date format like `05 Jan,2016` using `js` or `jQuery`. Below is my code.

```
var dateFormat = data.data[p].UserPackage.created;
alert(dateFormat); //2016-01-05 04:06:52


    var t = data.data[p].UserPackage.created.split(/[- :]/);
    alert(t); //2016,01,05,04,06,52

    var d = new Date(t[0], t[1] - 1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);

    alert(d); //Tue Jan 05 2016 04:06:52 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I have tried the above coding ,its working some how,but i want the exact format will look like `05 Jan,2016` or `Jan 05 2016`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php check it out

Answer (score 1):

**try [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)**

```
var dateFormat = '2016-01-05 04:06:52';
alert(moment(dateFormat).format('MMM YYYY'));
```

**Other Ways:**

```
var date = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // January 13th 2016, 12:53:43 pm
var date = moment().format('dddd');                    // Wednesday
var date = moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Jan 13th 16
var date = moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2016 escaped 2016
var date = moment().format();                          // 2016-01-13T12:53:43+08:00
```

**DEMO:**

```js
var dateFormat = '2016-01-05 04:06:52';

var formatedDate = moment(dateFormat).format('DD MMM YYYY');

$('#result').html(formatedDate);

alert(formatedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery-dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat) jquery plugin.

```
var  dateFormat=data.data[p].UserPackage.created;
 alert(dateFormat);//2016-01-05 04:06:52
document.write($.format.date(dateFormat, "dd MMM,yyyy"));
```

You can also convert it without the use of any library just like the example below

```
            //Pure javascript codes    
            var datestr = "2016-01-05 04:06:52";

            var monthNames = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
            var date = new Date(datestr);
            var day = date.getDate() <10? "0"+date.getDate():date.getDate();
            var convertedDate = day+" "+monthNames[date.getMonth()]+","+ date.getFullYear();
            document.write(convertedDate);
            console.log(convertedDate);
```

Comment: Its showing TypeError: $.format is undefined  ,I have not used any date js.
@jameshwart lopez

Comment: have you donwloaded the library? here is the [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat/master/dist/jquery-dateFormat.js)

Comment: Can i do it without using library?@jameshwart lopez

Comment: Yes ,your answer is correct ,can you plz run code snippet

Comment: are you talking about the jquery and dateFormat js files? My answer is using jquery plugin and pure javascript.Just choose between the two. If you dont want to use the jquery plugin just remove it and just pic the code starting from my comment pure javascript code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100553/discussion-between-shaddy-and-jameshwart-lopez).

Comment: @Shaddy I have update my answer not to use dateFormat.js

Comment: Ok.Thank you.Can you plz give  the code snippet of it?

Comment: Please check  the updated answer. I did remove all html tag and the dateFormat library.

Comment: Hii plz,provide the run snippet of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100561/discussion-between-shaddy-and-jameshwart-lopez).

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI has a date parser you can use that.

```
$.datepicker.parseDate( "dd MMM,yyyy", dateFormat );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution of my problem,but in a lengthy  way.well i have put it inside a function,from there i am just calling it,by passing required date as argument.Below is code,where i am calling it directly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
          var datestr = "2016-01-05 04:06:52";
          var t = datestr.split(/[- :]/);
          replace_date = datestr.replace(' ', 'T');
          var date = new Date(replace_date);
          var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
          month = month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
         if (month == "01") { month = "Jan"; }  else if (month == "02"){  month = "Feb"; }  else if (month == "03")  {month = "March";  } else if (month == "04")  {   month = "April";}else if (month == "05")    {   month = "May";  } else if (month == "06"){  month = "June";} else if (month == "07"){ month = "July";} else if (month == "08"){  month = "Aug";} else if (month == "09"){ month = "Sep";}else if (month == "10"){  month = "Oct";} else if (month == "11"){ month = "Nov";}else if (month == "12") {month = "Dec"; }
         alert(t[2] +' , ' + month +' '  + t[0]);
         });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
   
</body>
```